# Easy way of indicating the likelihood of a text?

Tags: text-mining, natural-language

I am trying to find out a simple way of quantifying *"how much sense a text paragraph makes"*. The measure is not necessarily fail-proof, but it has to be somewhat simple.

> One example measure that meets my need is defining the likelihood of a
>   text paragraph as
>
> $L=P(l_2\mid l_1)\cdot P(l_3\mid l_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot P(l_n\mid l_{n-1})$,
>
> where $P(l_2\mid l_1)$ stands for the probability of the second letter
>   $l_2$ comes right after the first letter $l_1$, and $n$ is the total
>   number of letters in a sentence.

There are definitely flaws in this definition of likelihood, but it is simple and thus favored in my applicaiton.

**What are some other comparatively easy measures that you have in mind?**

Comment: What you are describing here is essentially a character-level N-gram language model. Please take a look at the detailed description provided in this character language model page by LingPipe: http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/lm/read-me.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be sure that the words in your paragraph are correct, you could take the likelihood over words instead of letters, for example using the conditional $P(w_2|w_1)$ where $w_i$ are words. These probabilities you could get from Google: https://books.google.com/ngrams. If I got your question wrong, I am sorry and you may want to specify it a little more ;)

Comment: I wish to stay on the letter level, though. The reason is that I can't ensure that all the words are correct. They may be a collection of random letters. So pushing it up to the word level will not work.

Comment: Maybe you would like to include the probability that a series of letters are a misspelled word by $P(l_1,...,l_i|closestWords)\times P(closestWords)$ by using a string distance metric to find the closest correctly spelled word.